# How to restart a fragment in java?

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment in android and I want to restart the fragment after a certain task so that if I have some text feild and checks on the screen so that they will get their initial state.

```
public class upload_notice_fragment extends Fragment {

    public upload_notice_fragment(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upload_notice_fragment, container, false);
        uploadData();
        return fragment;
    }

    private void uploadData() {
        FirebaseFirestore storeReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("date", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()));
        map.put("time", new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()));
        storeReference.collection("date-time").add(map)
                .addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> {
                    // Restart the fragment here......
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                   .replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment)
                                   .commit();
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something Went Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                });
    }
}
```

Here is what I want to do in this.

i have tried to implement the code you provided but it is resulting in [Image For Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk8jT.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean "restart the fragment"? Better yet, what should the user see? If you can describe the user experience from the user's point of view, we will probably be able to better answer your question. In writing this, don't use words like "fragment" that the user doesn't know about.

Comment: Just to reset some textfields and checks on the screen , It is not good idea to restart your fragment as android system is going to recreate your fragment which is leading to memory consumption and bad user experience . It is better to reset by your code

Answer (score 0):

You can call that fragment again by using the following code

```
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment)
           .commit();
```

Instead of 'MyFragment' use your fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to restart a fragment:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
YourFragment yf = new YourFragment();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.YOUR_FRAGMENT_CONTAINER, yf).commit();
```

You have to replace YOUR_FRAGMENT_CONTAINER with your fragment container and YourFragment with the name of your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

when you are performing the task you can simply remove the fragment by using the followig line of code:
// Remove the current fragment

```
ft.remove(currentFragment);
```

and then again add the fragment by writing code:

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "YOUR_OWN_FRAGMENT_TAG");
ft.commit();
```

so the data you updated will be fetched again
or you can simply create a function for updating data by passing and call it when your task is done